# Compilation error with procedures in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am constantly facing a strange problem using Oracle SQL Developer.
I have a procedure in my schema, which is correctly compiled. However almost each time I close a database connection or restart computer, I see this procedure uncompiled althought I didn't make any changes in code...

Has anyone ever faced similar case? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: If you or anyone else changes a schema object(s) (tables, views, other stored procedures etc.) your procedure depends on, it will be invalidated.

Comment: Do you mean objects in dependencies section? I have a table in this section which is changed during the procedure execution. May the procedure invalidate itself?

Comment: how do you mean you see it 'uncompiled' - what does this mean exactly?

Comment: I mean there is a red cross next to procedure name instead of green tick. Moreover, the status in details section is "INVALID".